# Send Ctrl+q to multiple windows

Tags: autohotkey, multibox

I'm trying to write a script that sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+something to multiple windows. I wrote this:

```
; it's Eve Online - the window title is like this: "EVE - Character Name"
SetTitleMatchMode, 1
WinGet, eveid, list, EVE 
; I want to send Ctrl+Q to 2 windowed clients at once
^q::
KeyWait, {Ctrl}q, D
    ControlSend,, {Control down}q{Control up}, ahk_id %eveid1%
    ControlSend,, {Control down}q{Control up}, ahk_id %eveid2%
Return
```

but it doesn't works!

Any advice would me much appreciated!

Comment: Are you positive that `eveid` contains something? And to my knowledge, `KeyWait` only accepts one key. Furthermore, it doesn't make sense to wait for CTRL or Q to be pushed down. They have to be, otherwise the hotkey wouldn't have been triggered. Do you rather want to wait for them to be released.?

Comment: No, I just want to send Ctrl+Q to several windows at once. And you're right, I'm not sure that eveid catches any 'EVE' windows... Since all windows' names start with EVE, I thought I could use `SetTitleMatchMode, 1` - It worked while testing in Notepad.

Comment: As I said, the `KeyWait` makes no sense at all, you'll have to change that. If you don't know if your windows are found by `WinGet` I suggest you inspect the output.